# bash script fail execute in org-babel block

Tags: org-mode, bash

Below bash script works as a bash script but if execute it in org-babel block as below, it report error:

```
sh: 2: Bad substitution
```

code:

```
#+begin_src sh :results output
str="toto.titi.12.tata.2.abc.def"
arr=${str//[!0-9]/ }
echo "${arr[@]}"
#+end_src
```

Comment: `sh` is the lowest common denominator of shells. Try `#+begin_src bash` instead.

Comment: See the [ob-shell doc on Worg](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-shell.html) for details.

Comment: @NickD Thanks, yes change to bash works. but another issue with bash, I have submitted a new SO https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74972/command-output-not-captured-with-org-babel-bash