# command output not captured with org-babel bash

Tags: org-mode

Try the source block below with android device connected, the output is empty:

```sh
#+begin_src bash :results output
  out=$(adb shell date)
  echo $out
#+end_src
```

But if I change `bash` to `sh`, it outputs the date correctly:

```sh
#+begin_src sh :results output
  out=$(adb shell date)
  echo $out
#+end_src
    
#+RESULTS:
: Wed Dec 14 13:02:29 CST 2022
```

What's wrong with the `bash` code block?

Comment: Try using an `ssh` command  to a remote host that you have access to (`ssh remote.host.example.com date`) instead of the `adb` command and see if the shell makes any difference. If not, I would suspect `adb` but I cannot test that.

Comment: I installed `adb` and although running the `adb shell date` command from the command line works fine, I cannot get output from the source block with either `sh` *or* `bash`. Doing a similar `ssh` command works with both. There is funkiness galore, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: @NickD how to use ssh instead of adb?

Comment: You cannot replace `adb` with `ssh`, but they have similar properties, so I wanted to test the source blocks using `ssh`, rather than `adb`.  I just did `out=$(ssh <remotehost> date)` where <remotehost> is a machine I could ssh into: that works with both `sh` and `bash` code blocks. However, neither the `sh` code block nor the `bash` code block worked with `out=$(adb shell date)` - but I don't know why that is the case.

Comment: @NickD Great, it's helpful. and I found after out=$(adb shell date) lien, any echo command not work either. maybe the "adb shell" command has changed output property!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand the details yet, but it turns out that for both `ssh` and `adb`, you need to prevent them from reading `stdin` - otherwise, they block waiting for input. The confusing part is that it is not *always* necessary, but it is necessary in some (most?) cases, so it's better to be safe than sorry.

In the case of `ssh`, I got the same behavior (blocking) when I tried to `ssh` to `localhost`. `ssh` has a flag `-n` (or a setting `StdinNull`) that allows you to tell it to ignore `stdin`.

It turns out that `adb` has a similar flag in its `shell` subcommand, also denoted by `-n` (surely, not a coincidence).

So the final outcome is that both source blocks (`sh` and `bash`) will work fine, as long as you provide the flag:

```shell
#+begin_src sh :results output
   echo Start
   out=$(ssh -n localhost date)
   echo $out
   echo Done
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Start
: Thu Dec 15 01:24:31 AM EST 2022
: Done

#+begin_src bash :results output
   echo Start
   out=$(ssh -n localhost date)
   echo $out
   echo Done
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Start
: Thu Dec 15 01:24:36 AM EST 2022
: Done

#+begin_src sh :results output
   echo Start
   out=$(adb shell -n date)
   echo $out
   echo Done
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Start
: Thu Dec 15 01:25:14 EST 2022
: Done

#+begin_src bash :results output
   echo Start
   out=$(adb shell -n date)
   echo $out
   echo Done
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Start
: Thu Dec 15 01:25:19 EST 2022
: Done
```

Comment: Great, it works now. I try to add '\n' or ';' before but never work, '-n' works!